# computing correlation between values of one column

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a huge dataframe that looks like this:

```
gemeente    Partij  Perioden    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Totale bevolking (aantal)    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Geslacht/Mannen (aantal) Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Geslacht/Vrouwen (aantal)    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/Jonger dan 5 jaar (aantal) Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/5 tot 10 jaar (aantal) Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/10 tot 15 jaar (aantal)    Bevolking/Bevolkingssamenstelling op 1 januari/Leeftijd/Leeftijdsgroepen/15 tot 20 jaar (aantal)
0   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2007    135648.0    66669.0 68979.0 7986.0  7809.0  7514.0  7612.0  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2008    136481.0    67047.0 69434.0 7885.0  7853.0  7517.0  7680.0  ... 5.8 8.6 41.3    5.2 4.0 20.0    4.0 5.0 25.0    3.0
2   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2009    137775.0    67715.0 70060.0 7915.0  7890.0  7497.0  7628.0  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   's-Hertogenbosch    VVD 2010    139607.0    68628.0 70979.0 8127.0  7852.0  7527.0  7752.0  ... 5.6 8.4 40.7    5.4 4.0 20.0    3.0 5.0 24.0    3.0
4   Aa en Hunze PVDA    2007    25563.0 12653.0 12910.0
```

Partij consists of 6 possible labels and I have 270 columns. 
I want to compute the correlation and/or similarity between those 6 labels in Partij with the data from those 270 columns.

I tried `pd.groupby` but that only give me correlations between columns and not parties.

I tried to make a `pd.pivot_table` but and make the Partij as column names but then I still had all those normal column names and couldn't access the Partij names and compute correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Partij values appear as columns by using the transpose method of pandas' DataFrame:

```
df = df.transpose()
```